# Local Area Connection in Slacware 13

Tags: connection, modem, slackware, local

I have windows xp and slackware 13 on one computer, and the ISP provided me a new modem. There was manual how to configure it, so i start the web browser and typed it's ip address 192.168.1.1 and the web interface of the modem appeared so i logged in, that was easy.

But under slackware, i don't know how to enter in the modem config / web interface. I type in 192.168.1.1 but it's not working. Here's the output of ifconfig eth0 :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:a1:b0:01:18:28
          inet addr:169.254.73.8  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:febff400-febff4ff
```

How can i log in into the modem from linux, i.e. find it's assigned ip under slackware ? Thank you.

Comment: This post needs its title to be changed, i.e. changing _Slacware_ to _Slackware_. If I had a better reputation, I would do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, slackware isn't using DHCP, so you'll probably have to [set the IP address manually](http://linux-ip.net/html/basic-changing.html):

`ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

Or figure out why it's not doing DHCP:  [slackware dhcp](http://www.slackbook.org/html/network-configuration-tcpip.html)